# Unable to cast object of type DataServiceOrderedQuery to type Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceCollection

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-data-services

I have a database table called `Foos` that contains records of type `foo`. I have another table called `Bars` that contains records of type `bar`. I am trying to query the database for a collection `foos` and place that collection in a record of type `bar`.

Something like this: (both `foo` and `bar` are defined in a 3rd party library, I can examine the metadata, but I can't change them)

```
public class bar (from metadata)
{
    public DataServiceCollection<foo> Foos { get; set; }
}

private void SaveSomeFoos()
{        
    var bar = Container.Bars.Where(x => x.someProperty == someRequirement).First();
    bar.Foos = Container.Foos.Where(x => x.someProperty == someRequirement);

    Container.SaveChanges();
}
```

When I try and assign the results of the 2nd query to `bar.Foos` I get the error

```
Unable to cast object of type DataServiceOrderedQuery to type Microsoft.OData.Client.DataServiceCollection
```

How do I assign the results of `Container.Foos.Where(x => x.someProperty == someRequirement)` to `bar.Foos`?

Comment: Add this line to your code `var bob = Container.Foos.Where(someBool);` then hover your mouse cursor over `bob` to see what the _Type_ of `bob` is. _Hint - it isn't a collection._

Comment: Ok..  the return is IQueryable...  So I guess the question is how do I get the results of `IQueryable` into `DataServiceCollection`?  I will edit the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bar.Foos = Container.Foos.Where(x => x.someProperty == someRequirement);
```

should be changed to:

```
bar.Foos = new DataServiceCollection<Foo>(Container.Foos.Where(x => x.someProperty == someRequirement));
```

Also have a squiz at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee652823(v=vs.110).aspx .

Comment: `new DataServiceCollection` needed a type declaration, thus the answer turned out to be `bar.Foos = new DataServiceCollection<foo>(Container.Foos.Where(x => x.someProperty == someRequirement));`